# Omnet++ cannot import flora

Tags: omnet++, flora

I want to import flora to omnet++ version 5.2.1
I have already successfully imported inet. I downloaded both inet and flora from omnet++ website, [Here](https://flora.aalto.fi/).

After I added intent, I wanted to do the same with flora, clicked on it and selected build project. But came out this error :
[image: Error]

I also tried downloading flora from github and changed its folder name from flora-master to flora, but got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flora 1.0 clearly states that it requires omnet++ 6.0pre10 or later. Why are you using omnet 5.2.1 ? The error is because omnet 5.2 and 6.0 uses different message compilers.

Comment: Yes thanks. I was using flora 1. but the compatible version with my omnet version was 0.8